# What are the odds to get the right codes and access to the secret room in Diamond Heist?

Tags: payday-the-heist

Diamond Heist is probably the most hazardous map of Payday. In addition to the alarm boxes that are randomly dispatched in the level and the evacuation point that can be anywhere on the roof or nearby the safe's entrance (2 floors below!), there are two other big variables (and you'll need to be lucky with it in order to get the ["Shinobi" or "I pushed the button and lived" achievements](http://youtu.be/gXU2evgXBIM)):

1. Will your access codes work ?
2. Will you be able to access the secret room with the big diamond ?

Do you have any idea about the odds ?

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, please click on the "Answer Your Question" button in the answer area. The question body should be reserved for questions only. Please edit your question (you can do this with the Edit link located to the bottom left) to separate your answer out and post it separately.

Comment: Ok; I simply wanted to avoid multi-posting. I'll fix this asap (I can't answer my own question so soon - I have to wait 8 hours before).

Comment: You don't have to worry about multi-posting, as this is a different format than normal message boards. You're allowed to post more than one question at once and it won't be considered spamming (though try to use good judgement; 5-10 at once is a bit much because each new question pushes others off the frontpage). The time limit on answering your own questions is to also give other people a chance to offer their own answers, though it is acceptable to answer you're own as long as it is a good quality answer. The limit for newer users is mostly there to prevent reputation farming.

Comment: Ok !  I'll take that into account next time I'll use stackexchange.  Thanks ;)

Comment: I don't understand why.  I clearly see question marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first point, I'm pretty sure it's totaly random (and the odds are pretty weak).  Here's what [Payday's wiki says about that](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Diamond_Heist_-_Walkthrough):

> Now you head down to the bottom floor and enter a code, which fails
>   most times to work (**works 5-10% of the time**). If the code does not
>   work, the alarm will sound immediately and there is no longer any
>   point to staying quiet then you will need to start searching for the
>   CFO. If it does work, you can easily get all the diamonds without
>   breaking a sweat.

However, from my experience, 5-10% seems a little too low; I'd rather say 20%.  But maybe I've been lucky on this.

For the second point, I have to admit that I have no idea and can't find any good information about it.  Each player seem to have his own theory; personally I think it's completely random.  Sometimes, I did everything perfect (playing on overkill, get the 3 alarm boxes and the 10 gems without getting noticed, open the safe at the first try, don't break any glass anywhere) and the door wasn't there; just a brick wall.